# Swift local html file with space

Tags: html, swift, uiwebview

I am using this code to load a HTML file in web view:

```
class DiseaseWVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var web2: UIWebView!

    var index : Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if let file = self.index{
            print("got: \(file)")
        }else{
            print("didn't get")
        }
        //"Ace-VetBolus", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "HTMLFiles"
        let path: String? = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(getFileName(index!), ofType: "html", inDirectory: "HTMLFiles/disease")
        if let unwrappedPath = path {
            let requestURL = NSURL(string: unwrappedPath)
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)

            web2.loadRequest(request)
        }
    }

    func getFileName(index: Int) -> String{
        var fileNames: [String] = [
            "Anthrax",
            "Avian Colibacillosis"
        ]

        return fileNames[index]
    }
}
```

But as the file `Black Leg` has space it does not gets loaded. How do you load files with spaces?

Answer (score 0):

It may be the path is error, try to print out the path in console, in Foundation.Frameworks, it will have NSPathUtilities,
Use this function-NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains with NSPathUtilities 's ENUM to search where are your file.